# Trying to prove that $h_{n}(X,X) = 0$ in a homology theory $h_{n}$

Tags: homology-cohomology

By the excision property of Homology Theory, I know that

$h_{n}(X,X) \cong h_{n}(X-X, X-X)  = h_{n}(\phi,\phi)$, since the closure of $X$ in $X$ is equal to the interior of $X$ in $X$ ($X$ is both open and closed in itself).

Based on the axioms, it seems that I cannot conclude anything else about $h_{n}(\phi,\phi)$, which I *feel* should be $0$.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can easily use the long exact sequence and additivity to show $h_n(\emptyset, \emptyset) \cong 0$

Comment: ok I'll start there! thanks!

Comment: it worked, thanks a bunch!

Comment: No problem! Have fun!